# Ubuntu 18.04 gets super laggy

Tags: 18.04, performance

I have a Huwaei MateBook X Pro with 8 gigs of ram running 18.04.  It sometimes gets super laggy, to the point where I move the mouse, have to wait a second and then the mouse moves.  I am suspicious that it's Chrome, but I can't tell for sure.  I have a 2 gig swap space set up. I think this is somehow related to mem but not sure.   How can I diagnose this and anything you can recommend trying?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

update - adding output of extensions

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/home/kevin/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Diagnose by opening a terminal during a super-laggy time, and looking at the output of the `top` and `free` commands. If you need help understanding the output, then add the complete output to your question.

Comment: problem is, i cannot access the terminal until after the lag has passed.

Comment: You're smart - you will figure out a way. Here's one: Leave `top` open and visible waiting for a lag so you can watch your resource consumption.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this problem the other day, too.

1. Kali installed -> every 2 to 7 minutes a roundabout 10-30 seconds lag
2. Elive from USB (Persistent) -> everything fine
3. Elive installed on HDD -> lag
4. Ubuntu installed -> lag
5. Ubuntu Live -> everything fine.

There is no clue in top, `dmesg`, `tail -f /var/log/messages`, syslog, `smartctl --health /dev/sda` (SMART), Seatools (Samsung Disk Check tool), ... Even the HW clock is not affected from the lag.

Next I moved the hard disk to another Laptop -> same lag issue
Last I connected it via SATA-USB cable and performed some read/write tests -> same lag issue in dd, without affecting the OS.

Result: Nor the disk is broken (I/O Errors), nor the arm (parking position click). It seems there is an other chip (cache?) issue.

I recommend: If all commands/tools mentioned above are not helping, try a live-system, than try switch the disk.